# Не работает Hibernate Validator

Tags: java, hibernate, валидация

Есть такой код:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table (name = "users")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
@NotNull
@Size(
        min = 3,
        max = 30,
        message = "30 characters max"
     )
private String name;

@Min(5)
@Column (name = "age")
private int age;
}
```

Как вы видите, для полей name и age указаны некоторые условия, при несоблюдении которых должно выбрасываться исключение, однако ничего не происходит, я могу нарушать эти условия, например делая такой экземпляр:

```
UserService userService = new UserService();
User user = new User("T", 3);
userService.saveUser(user);
```

Но ничего не происходит, экземпляр спокойно себе создается и так же спокойно вносится в таблицу. Что я делаю не так?
В Maven зависимость имеется:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.17.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Необходимо также указать аннотацию `@Valid` у параметр контроллера или сервиса.

```
public void saveUser(@Valid User user) {...}
```